# How to return different results from Futures in Scala without ending up in nested if statements

Tags: scala, future

I am actually looking for a better Scala construct when it comes to return  different results from *Future* on different conditions.

Lets say, inside a *Future*, I need to do certain validations before return a successful result. There are two ways to do so.

**Way I:**

```
Future {
    if(!validation1()) return Future.failed("Validation1 failed!")
    if(!validation2()) return Future.failed("Validation2 failed!")
    if(!validation3()) return Future.failed("Validation3 failed!")

    Future.successful()
}.flatMap(identity)
```

**Way II:**

```
Future {
    if(!validation1())
        Future.failed("Validation1 failed!")
    else {
        if(!validation2())
            Future.failed("Validation2 failed!")
        else {
            if(!validation3())
                Future.failed("Validation3 failed!")
            else {
                Future.successful("Results")                
            }
        }
    }
}.flatMap(identity)
```

But there is a problem with the **Way I**, it results in exception *scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl*. You can find the explaination in this link: https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html

Which leaves us with **Way II**. The problem with this construct though is that it soon turns ugly with more number of validations.

Can anyone suggest a better way to express it?

*Please let me know if this is the right place for this question or this question needs to be expressed in a better way.*

*TIA.*

Comment: This is absolutely the right place for this type of question ;) However, both variants (even if they worked), seem to return something like `Future[Future[String]]`. Did you really want that? If you didn't want that, maybe you could try to adjust your examples until they faithfully represent what you wanted to achieve in your actual code.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand you correctly, but if you validate some form, you usually want to return information of all failed validations, not just the first you found.

Comment: It looks as if you might want to use [Validated](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html).

Comment: `pure(fx).flatMap(identity) = fx` for every `fx: Future[X]`

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I have fixed the code to return Future[String]. The reason I am returning Future.successful and Future.failed inside the outer future is because failure cases can also return exceptions in general. Actually that is what I am doing in the actual code.

Comment: @userunknown I am not really validating forms here. I understand the use case you are pointing at. Let's say, validations involve IO. So they basically are expensive. Which is why I don't want to do further validations if current validation fails.

Answer (score 4):

Consider to extract each validation into separate `Future`

```
def val1():Furure[String] = 
  if validation1() Future.failed("Validation1 failed") else Future.successful("Result")

def val2():Furure[String] = 
  if validation2() Future.failed("Validation2 failed") else Future.successful("Result")

def val3():Furure[String] = 
  if validation3() Future.failed("Validation3 failed") else Future.successful("Result")
```

and then chain them sequentially using `flatMap`

```
val1().flatMap(_ => val2()).flatMap(_ => val3())
```

or with syntactic sugar

```
for {
  _      <- val1()
  _      <- val2()
  result <- val3()
} yield result
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
def validation1(): (Boolean, String) // Tuple with e.g. (testResult, "Validation1 failed!")

def validation2(): (Boolean, String)

def validation3(): (Boolean, String)

val firstFound = Seq(validation1(), validation2(), validation3()).find(_._1)

if (firstFound.isEmpty) Success("Results") else Failure(firstFound.map{_._2}.get)
```